# powershell command to show application insight availability percentage

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

Looking to get availability percentage from azure application insight using powershell commands. I have BASH command az monitor app-insights metrics show, but since I want to run script in automation runbook, they dont support BASH commands. Does anyone have an idea for how to get same result with PS commands?

My last resort is to use invoke-webrequest or cURL but it has other challenges like API Keys.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Need to save  `availability.json` from the [json file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-metric-create-templates#template-for-an-availability-test-along-with-a-metric-alert) and Modify the resource as required and save the json as availabilityalert.parameters.json from the [json file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-metric-create-templates#template-for-an-availability-test-along-with-a-metric-alert)

```
 {  
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0", 
    "parameters": {
    "appName": {
    "value": "Replace with your Application Insights resource name"
    },
    "pingURL": {
    "value": "https://www.yoursite.com"
    },
    "actionGroupId": {
    "value": "/subscriptions/replace-with-subscription-id/resourceGroups/replace-with-resourceGroup-name/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/replace-with-action-group-name"
    },
    "location": {
    "value": "Replace with the location of your Application Insights resource"
    }
    }
    }
```

Get the `actionGroupId` in **Activity log -> select a specific log** here you can get `resourceid`.

[image]

You can create the availability test and associated alert using the template and parameters file using PowerShell.

```
Connect-AzAccount

New-AzResourceGroup -Name AvailabilityAlertDeployment -Location westus2

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName AvailabilityAlertDeployment -TemplateFile ./availabilityalert.json -TemplateParameterFile ./availabilityalert.parameters.json
```

For further [refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-metric-create-templates#template-for-an-availability-test-along-with-a-metric-alert)

Comment: This seems to be like creating availability report. We already have availability tests running. what is need is results of those.